# .NET 5 SDK publishing self-contained tries to restore 2.0.0 runtimes?

Tags: .net-core, .net-5

On a machine which only has the .NET 5.0 SDK installed (5.0.103), attempts to `dotnet publish` any application as a self-contained deployment will fail, even a simple blank console app. I get the same results with other RIDs like `win-x64`:

```
dotnet publish test.sln -c Release -r linux-x64 --self-contained true
```

The error messages indicate the build is requesting v2.0.0 runtimes for some reason. These runtimes aren't available from our internal package store (Artifactory) -- but I can't figure out why the build would request that version in the first place.

Notice `semVerLevel=2.0.0` at the end of the request:

```
Determining projects to restore...
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 
'https://[artifactoryURL]/FindPackagesById()?
id='Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.linux-x64'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
```

I had no issues with SCDs under SDK 3.1, although rolling the project framework back to 3.1 (but with SDK 5.0 installed) leads to the same problem.

I've tried additional switches like single-file and ready-to-run with no success. I can't reproduce this on my personal machine, but it's on a slightly newer version (SDK 5.0.200 and VS2019 16.9.0, versus 16.8.5 at work, the newest they allow us to use right now). I felt like our in-house packaging team messed up the VS or SDK install somehow, but they insist their changes are minimal and couldn't cause this.

Where are these dependencies expressed? Why does it happen? How do I fix it?

Comment: No repro on Mac - I use a Macbook to develop tools and sites that eventually get deployed as SCDs on Windows. I also publish for Mac to test the tools. The URL you posted tries to look up the runtime in your own package store and may be the result of a configuration issue. Can you reproduce the problem with a simple .NET Core console application, *without* involving your own build server or package store?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. What does your "csproj" file look like?

Comment: The request may be from the build script instead of .NET. Or perhaps, a unit test project still targets .NET Core 2.1 instead of 5.

Comment: It was a credentials issue -- since it was a work machine (with no Internet access), I had to re-type it here and I realized the 403 error meant I forgot to update the cached credentials used by NuGet CLI. Also the "2.0.0" is the NuGet API version, not the package version being requested.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- The `403` error was because my cached credentials used by NuGet CLI were out of date
- The `semVerLevel=2.0.0` specifies the NuGet API version, not the requested package

Running this to update my cached credentials fixed it:

`nuget update source "Artifactory" --username ""xxxx"" --password ""xxxx""`